# get the top urls from the logs

Tags: linux, sed, awk, head

I have a numbers of log files:

```
adsfs.demo.com_2022-07-11-0000-0001_cn.tgz 
adsfs.demo.com_2022-07-11-0000-0002_cn.tgz 
adsfs.demo.com_2022-07-11-0000-0003_cn.tgz 
adsfs.demo.com_2022-07-11-0000-0004_cn.tgz 
adsfs.demo.com_2022-07-11-0000-0005_cn.tgz 
...
```

the content of it like this:

```
google 16.122.87.76 12.48.167.135 80 adsfs.demo.com [11/Jul/2022:00:45:03 +0800]  1657471503.000 "GET https://adsfs.demo.com/mp/app/feeds/index.js?age=11&name=jock 1.1" 304 - 395 - - 1 "https://dhfs.demo.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 11; zh-cn; PDVM00 Build/RKQ1.201217.002) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/90.0.4430.61 Mobile Safari/537.36 HeyTapBrowser/40.7.39.5" "16.11.87.76" "-" 1 - 1
```

my requirement is get the topURLs with params from the 8th field of line, the 8th field is this:

```
"GET https://adsfs.demo.com/mp/app/feeds/index.js?age=11&name=jock 1.1"
```

I want the result is below:

```
https://adsfs.demo.com/mp/app/feeds/index.js?age=11&name=jock 13549
https://adsfs.demo.com/mp/app/feeds/index.js?age=12&name=jock 12541
https://adsfs.demo.com/mp/app/feeds/index.js?age=13&name=rose 1142
https://adsfs.demo.com/mp/app1/index.css?age=11&name=jock 1074
https://adsfs.demo.com/mp/app2/index.html 874
...
```

I tried this, but seems incorrect:

```
 zcat * | awk '{print $10, $17}' | awk '{a[$1]+=$10} END{for(i in a){print i, a[i]}}' | sort -rn -k 2 | head
```

```
https://adsfs.demo.com/user 0
https://adsfs.demo.com/union/adlogo/o_1512387525231.png 0
https://adsfs.demo.com/union/adlogo/logo_wo_b.png 0
https://adsfs.demo.com/union/adlogo/logo_w_b.png?aaa=aa.png 0
https://adsfs.demo.com/union/adlogo/logo_w_b.png?aa=1.jpg 0
https://adsfs.demo.com/union/adlogo/logo_w_b.png 0
https://adsfs.demo.com/union/adlogo/gdt_logo.png 0
https://adsfs.demo.com/signin 0
https://adsfs.demo.com/res/v2/feeds/mat_pic/202101/05/1000096829_1609822941972.jpg.short.webp?region=cn-north-1&x-ocs-process=image%252fresize%252cm_fix%252cw_640%252ch_320%252ffallback 0
https://adsfs.demo.com/res/v2/feeds/mat_pic/202101/05/1000096829_1609822941972.jpg.short.webp 0
```

Comment: Replace `$10` by `$2` in `... {a[$1]+=$10} ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More complete than my comment.
Full on awk script and call solution:

Awk script `./topurllogs.awk`

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    # Init for command head equivalent
    if (MAX == "") {
        MAX = 10
    }
}
{
    # For add (second awk call)
    h[$10] += $17
}
END {
    # Sorting order (command sort equivalent)
    #  Sort by hash values, numeric, descendant
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"
    i=0
    for (e in h) {
        i++
        # print hash key and value
        print e, h[e]
        # sort after n first hash key(s)
        if (i >= MAX) {
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Executable with this command:

```bash
chmod +x ./topurllogs.awk
```

Used like this:

```bash
zcat * | ./topurllogs.awk
```

or with another MAX value:

```bash
zcat * | ./topurllogs.awk -v MAX=8
```